# TronXY Windows 10 driver

Tags: prusa-i3, software, electronics, tronxy-x3, tronxy-p802

I am about to purchase a TronXY X3 or P802; but, my PC is running Windows 10.

The spec sheet for the printers does not list anything above Windows 7.
Is anyone using either of these printers with Windows 10?

Comment: This might be a better question to ask their tech support.

Comment: @Diesel TronXY is one of those chinese manufacturers, where you have better luck asking *GearBest* to send you replacement parts or refund than trying to get anyone from them on the line.

Comment: My problem is I have 2 tronxy printers #1 is a prusia-i3 ,#2 is a tronxy mini and when pluging in one or the other Repetiier always calls them both the MINI ,I tried to create another profile in Repetier but it will not let me so I end up fighting the computer to set up the correct printer ,The main diff between the 2 of then is one has a heated bed and is larger than the other and after I go into the printer settings and correct the bed size it will suddenly connect with no problems , the solution would be for the manufacturer to install a serial number that windows will read to connect and t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the printer supports using an SD card, you don't *need* to connect it directly to a PC. Serial over USB has been broken in the past in various Win10 builds, I've not tried it recently and I've not tried connecting my A8 to my PC recently either.

If you need to use USB, and can't make it work with Windows, there is always the option of using a Raspberry Pi single-board computer (which you can then connect to by VNC from your PC). Depending on the software you want to use, this might resolve any remaining issues you have.

Comment: What process/controller does the printer use?
I have heard printer uses an Arduino as a controller. Is that correct?

Comment: I now have the printer (X3) and it has a Melzi board and runs Repetier.  As you say I just use the SD card.  The printer is not close to my PC and my boys use it as well (they have their own PC); so, connecting a PC to it using USB probably will never make sense.  The SD card is the most practical thing at this point. Making it network accessible using a Raspberry Pi sounds like a good next step.

Comment: @markshancock connecting to a *TonXY X1* via "seraial over USB" worked fine in May and June 2018, the feature does however wobble as windows revisions change. To connect via USB allows to tune in the printer easier.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, (hobbyist level, FDM) 3D printers do not require dedicated drivers. They simply show up as a serial port (COMx), and you just need drivers for the USB-to-Serial chip used in the printer's electronics. This is usually an FTDI device, an AtMega32u or CH340. Drivers for those are readily available (and are usually even downloaded automatically through windows update).

The P802 appears to use a variant of the Melzi board, with an ATmega1284p (the less-powerful cousin of the 2560 found in most printers) as the main processor and it claims to have an (FTDI) FT232RL serial converter (I could not find any information on the X3). You should be aware of this, as there are many fake FTDI chips on the market, and [FTDI has been known to "patch" their drivers to break the clones](http://hackaday.com/2016/02/01/ftdi-drivers-break-fake-chips-again/). However, this problem is not specific to Windows 10. You can pretty much count on any 3D printer that works in Windows 7 working in Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tidbit that might be helpful to people.

- 3D Printer: Tronxy X1
- OS: Windows 10 (PC)
- SW: [Repetier-Host](https://www.repetier.com/)
  v2.0.5

The TronXY X1 boots at 115200 baud (you can change it in Configuration, but each power on it will reset to 115200).
In Repetier Printer Settings I set the baud rate to match at 115200.
My PC automatically recognized the USB device as USB-SERIAL CH340(`COM5`).

But...

I had to go into my PC's Devices and Printers, right-click the USB-SERIAL icon, go into Properties->Hardware->Port Settings: change Bits per Second from 9600 to 115200.

All good now.

Comment: X1 and X3 do use the same Marlin board. I can vouch for this with the March 2018 Windows 10 release. Not yet tested the May/June one.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 driver, go directly to the Microsoft update catalogue.
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=USB%5CVID_1A86%26PID_7523

Download the .cab file, extract the contents. Using Device Manager update the driver for the partially installed device. After the update TronXY-2 now appears as a COM port.